# Does include work like a function in php?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file as seen below that is a config file.
When I use  `return` in my code and `var_dump(include 'config.php');`
I see an array, but when I delete return the result is

> int 1

Does include work like a function in this case? And why I have to use `return` here?

```
<?php
return array(
'database'=>array(
    'host'=>'localhost',
    'prefix'=>'cshop_',
    'database'=>'finalcshop',
    'username'=>'root',
    'password'=>'',
),
'site'=>array(
    'path'=>'/CshopWorking',
)
);
```

Comment: question about `include` -> [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `include`is either "true"(1) or "false". If you put a `return` statement in the included file, the return value will be whatever you return. You can then do

```
$config = include config.php';
```

and `$config`will then contain the values of the array you returned in config.php.

Answer (score 2):

An [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) fetches PHP-code from another page and pastes it into the current page. It does not run the code, until your current page is run.

Use it like this:

config.php

```
$config = array(
    'database'=>array(
        'host'=>'localhost',
        'prefix'=>'cshop_',
        'database'=>'finalcshop',
        'username'=>'root',
        'password'=>'',
    ),
    'site'=>array(
        'path'=>'/CshopWorking',
    )
);
```

And in your file, say index.php

```
include( 'config.php' );
$db = new mysqli( 
    $config['database']['host'], 
    $config['database']['username'], 
    $config['database']['password'], 
    $config['database']['database'] );
```

This way, you do not need to write all that stuff into every file and it is easy to change!

Here are some statements with similarities:

1. [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) - insert the file contents at that point and run it as if it were a part of the code. If the file does not exist, it will throw a warning.
2. [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) - same as include, but if the file is not found an error is thrown and the script stops
3. [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) - same as include, but if the file has been included before, it will not do so again. This prevents a function declared in the included file to be declared again, throwing an error.
4. [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) - same as include_once, but throws an eeror if the file was not found.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `include` is **not** a function; it is a language construct. What that means is something you should Google for yourself.

Back to your question: what `include 'foo.php` does is literally insert the content of 'foo.php' into your script at that exact point.

An example to demonstrate: say you have two files, `foo.php` and `bar.php`. They look as follows:
**foo.php:**

```
<?php
echo "<br>my foo code";
include 'bar.php';
$temp = MyFunction();
```

**bar.php:**

```
<?php
echo "<br>my bar code";
function MyFunction()
{
    echo "<br>yes I did this!";
}
```

This would work, because after evaluating the `include` statement, your `foo.php` looks like this (for your PHP server):

```
<?php
echo "<br>my foo code";
echo "<br>my bar code";
function MyFunction()
{
    echo "<br>yes I did this!";
}
$temp = MyFunction();
```

So your output would be:

```
my foo code
my bar code
yes I did this!
```

**EDIT:** to clarify further, if you create variables, functions, GLOBAL defines, etc. in a file, these will ALL be available in any file in which you include that file, as if you wrote them there (because as I just explained, that is basically what PHP does).